# How to pass params in redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirecttoroute

I'm getting an error when trying to redirect to the users profile when erasing a tag from a photo. What am I doing wrong? Im getting stuck with this! Thanks!

```
def destroy
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
if @photo.destroy
redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', id: @user_id
end
end
```

Comment: What is the exact error you getting?

Comment: where is @user_id defined for this action??? What value are you trying to pass ?

Comment: I'm getting redirected to /users instead of the users profile..

Comment: @manu29.d you are right, I didn't have defined user_id. Instead, I did what RSB said, passing devise :id in the redirect_to as current_user. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@user_id` is missing in your action, if you are using devise, you can pass `id` of the logged in user by

```
redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', id: current_user.id
```

Comment: That did the trick, didn't realize I was missing the user id under the destroy method. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I helped, please accept the answer if it proved helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try
`redirect_to user_path(@user_id)`

Type `rake -T` in rails console to see all your routes

Comment: When i try that, I get redirected tu /users, but not the user profile... :(

Comment: Well yeah, ``@user_id`` is missed in your action.

Comment: That was the problem. So dumb...